# Oracle/Hibernate insert - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I am getting exception while inserting records into table.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8/ org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

i used JNDI datasource/Oracle for creating hibernate sessionFactory.

Here is the SessionFactory configuration :

```
<beans:bean id="jndiDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/TestDS" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.majesco.integration.model" />
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</beans:bean>
```

here hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <hibernate-configuration>       
    <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here model :

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="EVENT_AUDIT")
public class MessageControl implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="LMESSAGESEQ")
    private Integer messageseq;

    @Column(name="NMESSAGEID")
    private Integer messageid;

    @Column(name="STRMESSAGE_CD")
    private String messagecd;

    @Column(name="STRQUEUE_CD")
    private String queuecd;

    @Column(name="NMODULEID_FROM")
    private String moduleidfrom;

    @Column(name="NMODULEID_TO")
    private String moduleidto;

    @Column(name="NMESSAGE_STATUS")
    private String messagestatus;


    @Column(name="STRTRXNBR")
    private String transactionNBR;

    @Column(name="STRUUID")
    private String uuid;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Here DAO code:

```
   public class MessageAuditDaoImpl implements AuditDao{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory factory;


    @Override
    public void saveAuditMessage(MessageControl messageControl) {
        try {
            session=factory.openSession();
            session.save(messageControl);
            logger.info("Saved Message");
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception Occured"+e);
        }   
    }
 }
```

My code is working fine if I insert parameter lower than 8 and getting the exception for parameter grater than 8.

What's the issue or anything i missed in the code?

Comment: Where do you set this parameter you are talking about?

Comment: I mean MessageControl  bean having attributes/Coumns grater than 8

Comment: The MessageControl is an object? Right now it is hard to guess where your error comes from. How is the object you are trying to save created? What's inside of there?

Comment: i just tried by replacing dialect  org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect to org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect and its working fine. Maybe be its Oracle12cDialect specific issue for jndi datasource.

Comment: MessageControl  is hibernate entity and i am trying to save :           MessageControl messageControl = new MessageControl();
        messageControl.setMessagecd("ONLINE_RV");
        messageControl.setQueuecd("Q_FIN");
        messageControl.setModuleidfrom("FIN");
        messageControl.setTransactionNBR("Test");
        messageControl.setUuid("Some dummy data");

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace